# How to create volumes as non root user while starting applications using docker-compose

Tags: docker-compose

I have a volume `fa` under which I create application specific data, I run docker-compose as user `ubuntu` but folders are created as `root`. I am assuming creation as `root` shoud be avoided.

```
ls -l fa/
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 May 25 07:47 db
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 May 25 07:47 logs
```